# Cross-site collection navigation in SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, navigation, cross-site

Is there a way create or activate cross-site collection links. So if I'm under the Accounting Department site I can go into the Marketing Department site. I looked all over sharepoint and no luck.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 Managed Metadata Navigation should help in this case, following articles are useful:

It uses Pinned Terms
http://www.andrewjbillings.com/sharepoint-2013-managed-metadata-navigation-cross-site-collectionsit-kind-of-works/

It uses JSOM
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-global-navigation-sharepoint-2013/

**UPDATE**

Ooops, Managed Metadata Service & Managed Navigation are not available in SharePoint Foundation 2013.. read it after posting :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Sharepoint app for that. In your app, the app permission should be at least Site-Collection: Read. In this app, you should create an app part that query all the site in the site collection. And you can create html, css, or javascript functions for the navigation control.
I have created an app similar for that by using jsom but my app is creating a tree view display all the site in the site collection.